# Is there any way to compile a C# assembly statically into a project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'd like to compile the same build number into a number of separate assemblies written in C#.

When I update the build number in a single place, I need it to update in all of the individual assemblies.

Whats the easiest method to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a shared AssemblyInfo file as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx

Comment: Cool, I never realised you could do that!

Comment: Nice! The key it to select "Add as Link" (via the dropdown box in the "Add Existing Item..." dialogue), if you skip this step it creates a copy of the file rather than linking to it.